# How to created (table) and wrap (td) in span by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to created (table) and (td) by jQuery, and created (td) between span

if html

```
<table border='1' >
<tr>
<td class='ABC'>
  <b>avc</b>
  <span>
   <a href="http//gabc.com">ABC</a>
  </span>
   <span>
   <b>avc</b>
   <a href="http//gabc.com">ABC</a>
  </span>
  </br>
  <b>avc</b>
  <span>
   <a href="http//gabc.com">ABC</a>

  </span>
   <span>
   <b>avc</b>
   <a href="http//gabc.com">ABC</a>
  </span>
  </br>
    <b>avc</b>
  <span>
   <a href="http//gabc.com">ABC</a>

  </span>
   <span>
   <b>avc</b>
   <a href="http//gabc.com">ABC</a>
  </span>
  </br>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want like this: Between (span) and (b)

```
<table border='1' >
<tr>
 <td class='ABC'>


      <b>avc</b>
      <span>
       <a href="http//gabc.com">ABC</a>
      </span>


     <td>
       <span>
       <b>avc</b>
       <a href="http//gabc.com">ABC</a>
      </span>
      </td>
      </br>

       <tr>
          <td>
      <b>avc</b>
      <span>
       <a href="http//gabc.com">ABC</a>
      </span>
     </td>

     <td>
       <span>
       <b>avc</b>
       <a href="http//gabc.com">ABC</a>
      </span>
      </td>
      </br>

      </tr>

      <tr>

          <td>
      <b>avc</b>
      <span>
       <a href="http//gabc.com">ABC</a>
      </span>
     </td>

     <td>
       <span>
       <b>avc</b>
       <a href="http//gabc.com">ABC</a>
      </span>
      </td>
      </br>
     </tr>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How do I do that using jQuery?

I use this jQuery:

```
$(function(){
$(".ABC span").wrapall("<table border='1'></table>");
$(".ABC span").wrap("<td></td>");


});
```

but get an error.

How to create (table) and (td) using jQuery?

And create (td) between span

And thanks ^_^

Comment: Your HTML is *very* invalid.

Comment: you cannot put a td inside another td. Try to validate the html first.

Comment: Actually, except for `</br>` the markup *is* valid: *The end tag may be omitted, if it is immediately followed by a <th> or <td> element or if there are no more data in its parent element.* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td That said, OP... change it to `<br />`. Note, this will not fix your problem.

Comment: If you're using jQuery to generate DOM elements, creating this extra space between is not possible. Why? Because nobody cares about them. Browser doesn't care. Users don't care. Why do you?

Comment: wow, that HTML makes my eyes hurt.    I think that before you will be able to get some assistance you may want to review your HTML for proper syntax and to better state your question of what it is you are attempting to do.

Comment: The method you are trying to use it is called wrapAll not wrapall (all lowercase)

Answer (score 0):

Small type on your call to [.wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

```
$(function(){
   $(".ABC span").wrapAll("<table border='1'></table>");
   $(".ABC span").wrap("<td></td>");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/HappyiPhone/p3adf81t/